# represent JSON file in a java program for querying values by key

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to represent [this file](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-properties-dumper/blob/master/outputs/properties-en.json) in my java program.

What I want to do is quickly search through it by "key" value, so for instance, given the value `P26` I'd want to return `spouse`.

Maybe I can read it in as a `HashMap` using gson as I did with [this](https://github.com/h1395010/database_builder/blob/master/src/main/java/Q/Label_Assigner.java) program.

But what to do about this wonky structure:

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "P6": "head of government",
        "P7": "brother",
        ...
```

How could I fit that well into a `HashMap`? Is `HashMap` even the best choice?

---

I've sort of simplified it to this:

```json
{
    "P6": "head of government",
    "P7": "brother",
    "P9": "sister",
    "P10": "video",
    "P14": "highway marker",
    "P15": "road map",
    "P16": "highway system",
    "P17": "country",
    "P18": "image",
```

I've tried to use this code, but it outputs `null`

```java
/*
 * P values file
 */
String jsonTxt_P = null;

File P_Value_file = new File("properties-es.json");
//read in the P values
if (P_Value_file.exists())
{
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream("properties-es.json");
  jsonTxt_P = IOUtils.toString(is);
}

Gson gson = new Gson(); 
Type stringStringMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType(); 
        Map<String,String> map = gson.fromJson(jsonTxt_P, stringStringMap);
        System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: why dont use properties of java inbuilt function?  refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_properties_class.htm

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because that file is not a `Map<String, String>`. it has a properties element, which contains a mapping, and a missing element, which contains an array. This mismatch will cause Json to return null, which is what you're seeing. Instead, try doing this:

```
public class MyData {
    Map<String, String> properties;
    List<String> missing;
}
```

And then, to deserialize, do:

```
MyData data = gson.fromJson(jsonTxt_P, MyData.class);
Map<String, String> stringStringMap = data.properties;
```

This will make the data structure match the structure of the json, and allow json to properly deserialize.